# Fill allocated memory with data from another process

Tags: c++, memory-management, read-write

Okay, this question is not regular, and maybe stupid, cause im not familiar with pointers and links in c++:

So i have some data in memory of another process (http://prntscr.com/zmfb4p), it's about 1200-1600 bytes.
I have a driver, which can do kernel read-write to needed process.
I have a user-mode application, which one communicate with driver like that:

```
int reading_data = driver.readvirtualmemory<int>(<processId>, <adress to read>, <size to read>);
```

It works as intended with small data types, but i can't understand, how to get "large" amount of bytes and store it:

Allocating memory to store data:

```
char* test_buf = new char[size_matricies_buffer];    // allocating memory and creating a pointer to it ~1200-1600 depends on situation
*test_buf = driver.ReadVirtualMemory<char>(<process>, <address>, static_cast<uint32_t>(size_matricies_buffer));  // filling allocated memory with data?
```

It compiles, and works, but when im trying to get access to *test i get an error:

```
cout << "buf: " << *test_buf << " | " << &test_buf << endl;
```

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF6D1DD1671 in Mysoftware.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000C21C833C.

Any idea what im missing here?

Comment: ***violation writing location 0x00000000C21C833C*** Your OS says you tried to write data. I am not sure the error comes from the line presented.

Comment: It makes no sense to allocate memory and then read a block and return something and put it into a `char`. What exactly does the `ReadVirtualMemory` do? Why not give it the buffer to copy the data into?

Comment: yeah, maybe, i was confused, because *test_buf = driver.<blabla> was completed by VS when i run solution.

Comment: This function makes no sense because it returns an int? Int is 4 bytes, so what happens if I ask the function to read 5 bytes, how does it return the extra bytes?

Comment: In `cout << "buf: " << *test_buf ` the `*test_buf ` is most likely not a null terminated string. Although I would expect `Access violation reading location` instead of `Access violation writing location`

Comment: I don't think `*test_buf = driver.ReadVirtualMemory<char>() ...` is correct. However I don't know where you got this function from.

Comment: Please edit your question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: trying to adapt for stackoverflow, sry for that.
@user253751  no, function returns <char> type of data. Expected size to return ~1600 bytes or so.

Comment: All I see here is a memory-protection violation.  You *assume* that you know why it happens – that it is related to size, etc.  Hence, this is an *"XY Problem."* Use the address to locate the actual place in the code where the exception is raised.  Be very methodical and assume nothing.

Comment: @RomanRzaev Well how does it return a char? That makes no sense. Because a char only holds one byte. You can't put 1600 bytes in a char. It's not possible. You would need 1600 chars to hold 1600 bytes.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen `ReadVirtualMemory` calls ``KERNEL_READ_REQUEST``  to my driver. Driver  recieving call and doin `MmCopyVirtualMemory` from target's process to mine solution

Comment: @user253751 It's a <type of data> which im expected from function. And yes it return me what im asking for, as i said before in question. But only with small amounts of data, like 1-20 bytes, i never tryed more.

Comment: @RomanRzaev you didn't answer how it's possible to store 1600 bytes in a char. Which address does the driver copy to in your process?

Comment: @user253751 example of data address to copy in screenshot above( http://prntscr.com/zmfb4p ), address is non-static, im getting it a lot before. For example: `0x1f78fefc040` does it change something? 
And yes, it's not possible to store 1600 bytes in a char, but it's possible to store 1600 bytes of char >_<

Comment: @drescherjm that's why im ask here. In left side of function i'v got (as i assume) an pointer to allocated memory, on right side - working function as intended, but in result it drops me an mailfunction ;/

Comment: @RomanRzaev You wrote the ReadVirtualMemory function, right? Why can't you explain how that function works?

Comment: @user253751 i will provide answer for my question bit later(i found solution). Not sure how to define function here, to keep it "readable", anyway thanks for patience.

Comment: You basically seem to be asking why your function that you wrote doesn't work but you won't provide the code for the function. For that reason, I am voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basic function readVirtualMemory doin this(i guess i presented too short explanation above, but nvm now):

```
template <typename type>
type ReadVirtualMemory(ULONG64 ProcessId, ULONG64 ReadAddress, SIZE_T Size)
{
    type Buffer;

    KERNEL_READ_REQUEST ReadRequest;

    ReadRequest.ProcessId = ProcessId;
    ReadRequest.Address = ReadAddress;
    ReadRequest.pBuff = &Buffer;
    ReadRequest.Size = Size;

    if (DeviceIoControl(hDriver, IO_READ_REQUEST, &ReadRequest, sizeof(ReadRequest), &ReadRequest, sizeof(ReadRequest), 0, 0))
    {
        return Buffer;
    }

    return Buffer;
}
```

And KERNEL_READ_REQUEST is:

```
   typedef struct _KERNEL_READ_REQUEST
{
    ULONG64 ProcessId;
    ULONG64 Address;
    PVOID64 pBuff;
    ULONG64 Size;

} KERNEL_READ_REQUEST, * PKERNEL_READ_REQUEST;
```

So the problem was with necessary type definition in original function and structure of function. Problem was solved with next solution: adding a new kernel_read function, without type declaration, with pointer to buffer which needs to be filled by read data. (thanks to  @SamiKuhmonen for idea):

```
    bool ReadBuffer(ULONG64 ProcessId, void* buffer, ULONG64 ReadAddress, SIZE_T Size, bool secondary = false)
{
    KERNEL_READ_REQUEST ReadRequest;

    ReadRequest.ProcessId = ProcessId;
    ReadRequest.Address = ReadAddress;
    ReadRequest.pBuff = buffer;
    ReadRequest.Size = Size;

    if (DeviceIoControl(hDriver, IO_READ_REQUEST, &ReadRequest, sizeof(ReadRequest), &ReadRequest, sizeof(ReadRequest), 0, 0))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

After that my buffer

```
char* matricies_buf_buf = new char[size_matricies_buffer];
driver.ReadBuffer(pid, matricies_buf_buf, transform_data[0], size_matricies_buffer);
```

was filled with needed data.

sry for some ppl, who was annoyed with that question, it's my first time when i trying to ask a question and stackoverflow.